# Yup validation schema for dynamically added grid fields

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-hook-form, yup

I have a JSON model as below. This can be visualized as grid rows (added/removed dynamically i.e. new rows can be added to the gridItems and also removed)

```
{
    "sections": [{
        "id": "my-section-1",
        "gridItems": [{
            "fields": [{
                "id": "field1",
                "value": "Row 1 Col 1"
            }, {
                "id": "field2",
                "value": "Row 1 Col 2"
            }]
        }, {
            "fields": [{
                "id": "field1",
                "value": "Row 2 Col 1"
            }, {
                "id": "field2",
                "value": "Row 2 Col 2"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I map this JSON to fields on the UI via React Hook Form.

Also for uniqueness for registering field (and also for setting defaultVales), I append -index to the above structure at runtime
i.e. these fields id's are actually parsed to

```
field1-0, field2-0, field1-1, field2-1
```

Now, I want to define/map these fields to Yup validation schema and am thinking of the best way.

So, all the 'field1' across rows would have the same validation...similarly for 'field2'

1. Can I define a Yup validation using pattern i.e. say for field1-X
   OR
2. Do I need to somehow use Yup.array here...again the issue is I do not directly render these fields from the above structure, but instead copy these to a local state variable object (parsed with -index) and using that render UI fields.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend passing index with fields for examples

```
grid:[
{index:0,fields:[...]
},...]
```

and then you schema will be something like this

```
yup.object().shape(
grid:yup.array().of(yup.object().shape(
{index:yup.number(),fields:yup.when("index", 
{       is: 0,//index goes here
        then: yup.object().shape({
id:yup.string(),
value:yup.string() //this will be changed
})
      })}))
)
```

you can change when operator for more complex function like this

```
yup.object().shape(
grid:yup.array().of(yup.object().shape(
{index:yup.number(),fields:yup.when("index", 
(index,schema)=>{
if(index===1){
return yup.object().shape({
id:yup.string(),
value:yup.string() //this will be changed})}else{
return //other schema
}
)

      })}))
)
```

don't mind the formatting

Comment: Thanks a lot...Quite close to what I am looking for....but just one thing....You have....
is: 0,//index goes here

Comment: Actually my grid rows can get added dynamically and I want the same validation for all columns across the different rows....so think all First name would be same validation, all Last name would be same validation

Comment: i more thing you can have a state for validations as well useState to set initial validations then update validation schema when you set fields i am commenting from mobile but i will give you a sample code for that as well i have set validations on updating fields as well

Comment: Sure...Thanks a lot in advance for the sample code as that would be really helpful...So to reiterate, I am primarily looking at ways to handle Yup validation for fields that would get added in "future"..

Comment: her you go sorry for the delay 
```
const [validation, setValidation] = useState(yup.object().shape(
    {
      // initial validations go here
    }
  ))

  onChange={(e)=>{
//condition new row is added or any condition you want 
setValidation({
  yup.object().shape({
  //newValidation schema

  })
})
//after this you can set formik value through 
formik.setFieldValue("name",e.target.value) 

  }}
```

Comment: Thanks again....But I am quite confused...you have yup.object() inside useState...Also , when you sare saying setValidation with newValidation schema....I am not clear how that new validation schema should be set with the additional row that has been added now

Comment: okay yup functions return an object which validates so using it inside useState make a default validation schema object right? now when you are adding new row it must be onClick or onChange of an input right? so update that validation object on onClick or onChange which ever function is applicable here i think you are adding new row with a button on that would be onClick of that button you have to update the validation schema object thats it